# How to create a simple retrieve API after the connection has been done?

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB and Nodejs and I would like to know how to create a very simple find all the records from a collection.

What I have done so far and it is listening to port 5000 in the console log:

```
const express = require('express')
const BodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')
const port = 5000;
const app = express()
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var db;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user1:mypassword@cluster0.2sgiu.mongodb.net/ecommerce?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

app.listen(port,() => {
    MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err, database) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error occurred connecting to MongoDB...")
        }
        console.log(`Listening to part ${port}...`)
      });
})
```

How do I proceed from here to create an API to retrieve all records from a Books collection after the connection has been done?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first save the database object that is returned to you by the callback function of `connect` (let's called that `db`).

Then, you can use that object to access your collections like "Books" in this example:

```js
db.Books
```

To get all the documents inside a collection you can use the [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method with an empty object as the argument.

```js
const books = db.Books.find({});
```

If you want to tie MongoDB queries to your Express app, you should a create routes in which, you can respond the request with data that you fetched. Considering that this data is going to be publicly available.

```js
app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
  const books = db.Books.find({});
  res.status(200).send({ books });
});
```

You can now make a `GET` request to `localhost:5000/books` and it should respond to you back with the contents of the Books collection. Either use your browser or `curl` to make the request.

```sh
$ curl localhost:5000/books
```